# Html to $scope or $rootScope?

Tags: angularjs, scope, rootscope

Imagine that in an HTML page I have the following input and I'm not using controllerAs.

```
<input ng-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Where will I be able to access the **password** value in the $scope or $rootScope ?

I can specify which want to enter the model information ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/HJ8fCVkxPT78CgHwOldl?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're referencing to the $scope. For targeting $rootScope you should use:

```
<input ng-model="$root.password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Comment: I tested now , the way I exemplified and realized that you can access the model in both ($scope and $rootScope) .

Comment: $scope inherits from $rootScope.

Comment: I guess that you html snippet located not inside the Controller, just inside ng-app.

Answer (score 0):

To bind a variable to rootScope which is provided by ng-app directive of every angular application you can use:

```
<input ng-model="$rootScope.password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```